# Turning object columns except one into integer (pd.to_numeric not working; data listed as object and errored as float)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have run into a problem were my data is being listed as an object at some point, and then given an error due to being a 'float'

I have columns that are typed as objects right now here:

```
Household    Energy   Water   Food
Brunt         23%      34%    43%
Liv           17%      29%    54%
Rowan         37%      22%    41%
Lisz          32%      32%    36%
```

I'm trying to remove the '%', turn these into decimal form and turn these into `int` with the following method:

```
df.update(df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x.str.rstrip('%'),downcast='integer',errors='coerce'))/100)
```

But as I check with `df.info()`, it states the objects as still objects.

I'm trying to plot this into a stacked horizontal barchart where the % value is on the respective bars us matplotlib. But when I try to apply the following:

```
df.plot( 
    x = 'Household', 
    kind = 'barh', 
    stacked = True, 
    title = 'Cluster 1021 HH Consumption', 
    mark_right = True) 

df_total = df.iloc[:,-17:-1].sum(axis=0)
df_rel = df[df.columns[1:]].div(df_total, 0)*100
  
for n in df_rel:
    for i, (cs, ab, pc, tot) in enumerate(zip(df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], df_rel[n], df_total[n])): 
        plt.text(tot, i, str(tot), va='center')
        plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center')
```

It gives me `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` in the second `for`. How can this be? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly creates a list of columns which contains `'%'` symbol and whom you want to convert into `int`:-

```
col=df.columns[1:]
```

The output of above code is `Index(['Energy', 'Water', 'Food'], dtype='object')`

You can make use of `for loop`,`replace()` method and `astype()` method:-

```
for x in col:
    df[x]=df[x].str.replace('%','').astype(int)
```

Now if you type `df.info()` it will shows `int`

Comment: For some reason, this comes out as a KeyError: 'Energy' on my end

Comment: Thank you so much! It did convert to int! But now it gives me TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable where the previous TypeError was. I'm sorry, I don't know why it's always a non-iterable error

Comment: what are you trying to do here :-`for n in df_rel:` bcz your `df.plot()` working fine

Comment: Yes, the ```df.plot()``` works fine. The ```for n in df_rel:``` That is where I try to put the % values on the horizontal barchart from the ```df.plot()```

Comment: ohh..I don't know about this but you can wait for someone else to answer this question or you can change/update your current question mentioning about your current problem....or ask another question about this as you solved dtype conversion part of it

Comment: I will just ask again for this specific problem. Thank you!